# Read html table with pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, html-table

I'm scraping tables from this website http://www.nowgoal.com/analysis/1514180.html
(in case you click and the match is already gone, from the website Nowgoal you can get any other match with the same structure.

This page has several tables, and so far my code, which worked, was as follows:

```
name='Head to Head Statistics'
tabla=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'''//tbody[descendant::*
    [contains(text(),"{}")]]'''.format(name))))

tablas=pd.read_html(tabla.get_attribute('outerHTML'),header=0,skiprows=(0,2))[0]
```

Where I already optimized it adding header and skipping rows. The problem is, when i try the table with `name='Live Odds Comparison'` I get the following error when trying to read html with pandas

```
>>ValueError: No tables found
```

I have debugged a little and the outerHTML attribute works fine and prints what it should, but neither that nor using innerHTML returns the table as it should and as it does with the others. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, though I still don't understand why with this table doesn't work the usual approach, what works is looking for a parental node of the one I was searching. So, for it to work, the only thing that should be changed is

```
tabla=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'''//div[contains(@id,"liveCompareDiv") and descendant::*
[contains(text(),"{}")]]'''.format(name))))
```

This way you find the table I was looking for. My guess is somehow the internal code of tbody node differs from one table to another and that creates the wild behaviour.

Edit because now I know why, I think. After `tbody` in the tables that worked there are two `tr` nodes, one containing the title and another containing the data. In this table though there still is the `tr` node containing the title, the second containing the data is not, and the rows are all uncontained.